# How to read a file in Node JS into a buffer from end to start (backwards)?

Tags: node.js, file, io, stream, buffer

I'm looking for a performance-oriented way to read a file into a buffer backwards (from end to beginning).

The zip file format has a crucial end of central directory record at the end of the file (it could be n bytes back, there is a signature I need to find to know I have got it, so I can't just read the last 22 bytes of the file since there is an optional 64K comment in there).

I couldn't find any discussion on Stack Overflow or using Google on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this module: https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools

You could use the reverse function given by the module, which creates a new buffer in memory of equal length and loops through the original buffer from the end, appending each element to the front of the new buffer.

You would be better off simply using a loop with the starting index as `buffer.length - 1` and decrementing until you get the data you want.